# Hover and pressed in javafx

Tags: css, button, javafx, hover, pressed

I wrote this css code for button pressed

```
  .button:pressed {
        -fx-scale-y: 0.9;
        -fx-scale-x: 0.9;
}
```

and this for button hover

```
 .button:hover {
        -fx-background-color: #383838;
        -fx-scale-y: 1.1;
}
```

and it doesn't scale down because for the button to be clicked it obviously has to be hovered. Is there any way to cancel the hover code when the button is being pressed?

Answer (score 19):

Either:

reverse the order of the rules, so that the rule for `pressed` comes after the rule for `hover` (and thus takes precedence):

```css
.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #383838;
    -fx-scale-y: 1.1;
}

.button:pressed {
    -fx-scale-y: 0.9;
    -fx-scale-x: 0.9;
}
```

or, make the rule for `pressed` more specific than the rule for `hover` by explicitly applying it to a button that is both pressed and hovered:

```css
.button:pressed:hover {
    -fx-scale-y: 0.9;
    -fx-scale-x: 0.9;
}

.button:hover {
    -fx-background-color: #383838;
    -fx-scale-y: 1.1;
}
```

Comment: If the answer helped you solve your problem, you should select it as correct.

Comment: @FernandoGaggero (Previous comment)